# Multiple conditional formatting rules across multiple ranges?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I need to do the following. Highlight a row if cell E contains a number greater than 30 AND cell L contains a number greater than 100. This rule needs to be applied to all rows. Can you help please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use [CONDITIONAL FORMATTING](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/quick-start-apply-conditional-formatting-HA010370614.aspx):

**1)** Select all cells in the sheet (by pressing on the top left corner):

[image]

**2)** *With selected range* go to *"Conditional Formatting -> New Rule.."*

[image]

**3)** Select *"Use formula..."* rule type, enter formula `=AND($E1>30,$L1>100)`. Choose desired format and press *"OK"*

[image]

**RESULT:**

[image]

Comment: You're an absolute star. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: That's weird. It worked the first time but not when I adjusted the 'greater than' values. I have cleared all formatting and started again but now it won't even work with your exact formula. I'm obviously doing something wrong but I have followed your instructions exactly. Any ideas?

Comment: show your new formula please:) Have you cleared all previous formatting relues?

Comment: Ha! you have a percent format for `L` column! actually `100%` is `1`, `255%` is `2.55` and so on. change formula to `=AND($E1>20,$L1>0.4)` (or to `=AND($E1>20,$L1>40%)`)