# Excel match columns from different sheets

Tags: excel

Trying to work with some excel here.. And can not get my head around how to do stuff.

I have two sheets with data.
Sheet1 consists of :

```
  A     B     C
User  UserID Area
```

Sheet2 consists of :

```
  A  
UserID
```

Sheet1:B may consist of the same userid on multiple rows.
Sheet2:A has an ordered list without duplicated userid's

I would like to get the Sheet2:A userid matched against Sheet1:B. If matched, insert Sheet2:B userid into Sheet1:D (new column) on the matched row 
If above matched, and Area = 2, mark row with Color red.

Kind Regards
Lars

Comment: You want to do that with formulas on sheet or VBA?

Comment: Formulas. I have even less experience with VBA ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In column D on sheet1 add this
`=IF(IFERROR(MATCH(B2,'Sheet2'!A:A,0),"")<>"",B2,"")`

Then select all cells, then Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula... > `=AND($D1<>"",$C1=2)` and select your color as required. Note that your conditional formula is using multiple criteria.

Here is more about Conditional Formatting: [Multiple conditional formatting rules across multiple ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21697848/multiple-conditional-formatting-rules-across-multiple-ranges)